# How can I keep terminal input and output separate. So that what I am typing does not get confused by output

Tags: bash, input, lxterminal

What I mean by that is when a program is running (let's say, telnet), any inputted text gets lost when something is written on the screen. For example, on a chat server,

I type

*> Hey, I'd like to ask y*

Suddenly I receive a string, and now my screen looks like this

*> Hey, I'd like to ask yHey, what's up?*

I can still continue to write and hit return to successfully send the string, but I'd like to have my input move down like so

*Hey, what's up?*

*> Hey' I'd like to ask y*

How can I do that? I use bash and lxterminal

**UPDATE**
So here's a quick and dirty solution: anytime your input gets lost, press `^R` to recover it.

Comment: It's the same problem, but it's not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Version 2

Version 1 (below) did not work, as the input went to the parent terminal, but is not processed. So I had another go. We have to have the program run in the input terminal, it gets its input as normal. Then directs its output to the other terminal. I think it should work, but have not tested (no mud server).

```
xterm -e bash -c "telnet mud > '$(readlink -f /dev/stdin)'"
```

## Version 1

I used to use a separate terminal for input.

Create input terminal by doing:

```
xterm -e bash -c "cat > '$(readlink -f /dev/stdin)'"
```

---

## How it works

- First the `readlink -f /dev/stdin` determines the terminal you are in. It does this by following the symlinks from `/dev/stdin`. These are dynamic (they change), depending on the process that looks.
- The command now looks like `xterm -e bash -c "cat > '/dev/pts/x'"`
- Next xterm runs and launches `bash` that launches `cat` redirected to this terminal.

Comment: It's a great idea, thanks for sharing. Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Thank you for explaining it!

Comment: I just tried it out, and it doesn't work. The input is sent over, but it's not registered. If I input "man tty" it's printed without any action. The same is true for telnet. I tried both xterm and lxterminal. I'm on archlinux. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh Yes. Now you point it out, it is obvious. I will have another think.

Comment: It works! It works with lxterminal and with xterm. Thanks again!

Comment: There are still problems with version2. Depending on what you connect to, it may not work.